# How to efficiently compress many small files to many small .tar.gz files with gzip?

Tags: python, linux, shell, gzip, tar

I have millions small *.csv files, and I want to compress them each with gzip.

It's ok to compress each of them with gzip by a loop, but it's not efficient enough.

I wonder if there is a way to do this efficiently? By multiprocessing or some other ways?

Comment: If you're creating one compressed file per input file, why `tar.gz` and not just `.gz`? The entire *point* of `tar` is to archive multiple input files together into a single stream.

Comment: That said, if you care about efficiency, I wouldn't use gzip for this purpose at all. Choose a file format that lets you use a prebuilt, shared compression table and you'll get a far better ratio when compressing lots of small files; see for example [`zstd`](https://github.com/facebook/zstd).

Comment: That said, if your goal is just to avoid the inefficiency of starting gzip once per file, `find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec gzip -- {} +` will pass as many filenames to each copy of `gzip` as fit on the command line.

Comment: Put them all in a single `.tar.gz` file. This will use a single LZW compression table for all of them combine, which should produce more effective compression. If you really want them in separate files, use GNU Parallel to run gzip in parallel.

Comment: See Charles' comments above and have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166037/2836621

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`zstd`**](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/) as per [*Charles Duffy*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979375/how-to-efficiently-compress-many-small-files-to-many-small-tar-gz-files-with-gz#comment98608685_55979375):

```
cd csvdir  # go to where the million .csv files are
zstd --train `find . -name '*.csv' | shuf -n 100`
mv dictionary csv.dict
zstd -T$(nproc) -9 -D csv.dict -o csvfiles.zstd *.csv
```

This makes a dictionary from a random sample of one hundred *.csv* files, then uses all the CPU's cores to efficiently compress the million files to *csvfiles.zstd*.