# Specify number of cores used in tar with lbzip2

Tags: parallel-processing, compression

Normally I use a combination of tar and bzip2 to store directories.  However, some are quite large, so I've tested a couple compression algorithms that allow parallel processing.  Here are the two options I've tried so far:

```
tar cf dst.tar.bz2 src --use-compress-program=lbzip2

tar c src | pigz > dst.tar.gz
```

The lbzip2 algorithm is both faster and yields a better compression ratio.  However, pigz allows me to specify the number of processors it uses.  Can I specify the number of processors used in the lbzip2 example?

Comment: You might have a look here and consider doing something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166037/2836621

Comment: Based on tar docs (bottom of [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html), you can use script as a compress program. The script can then invoke lbzip2 with whatever additional parameters you want.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Now that is an interesting option.  I glanced over the docs and it looks like parallel is a very powerful tool, so I need to understand it better before implementing it.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @DanMašek You pointed me in the right direction!  After RE-reading the lbzip2 docs I saw the -n option (very first option listed...but I looked right over it before).  tar cf CL51.tar.bz2 CL51 --use-compress-program=lbzip2 -n 4 works for setting number of processors to 4.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer and accept it and bag the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the tar and lbzip2 docs I think the following line should work (it doesn't):

```
tar cf dst.tar.bz2 src --use-compress-program=lbzip2 -v -n 4
```

You can list options/flags after the lbzip2 call (i.e. the -v successfully set the output to verbose), but for some reason the -n flag is not working here.  If anyone can point out the problem/solution I will be grateful.

However, lbzip2 can be used with tar via the following:

```
tar c src | lbzip2 -n 4 > dst.tar.bz2
```

This is similar to the original gzip call, but still (from my tests so far) works faster than gzip.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar cf file.tar.bz2 src --use-compress-program='lbzip2 -n8'
```

worked for me.

Comment: Hmm, that's still not working on my machine.  I get the following error: tar (child): lbzip2 -n8: Cannot exec: No such file or directory