# Is there a script to compress every single file in a directory and ouput it to another Directory?

Tags: bash, scripting, compression, gzip

So I'm looking to compress the files in a given directory, for example /etc/input and output the files in /etc/output, and it should be like:

```sh
$ ls /etc/input
file1
file2
file3

$ script.sh

$ ls /etc/output
file1.zip
file2.zip
file3.zip

$ ls /etc/input
```

For now, what i wrote looks like this:

```sh
find . -type f -print | while read fname ; do
    mkdir -p "../output/`dirname \"$fname\"`"
    gzip -c "$fname" > "../output/$fname.gz"
done
```

Comment: use `-print0 | while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d $'\0'` for file names with spaces

Comment: See here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166037/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find`, but I think it's simpler with pure Bash.

```sh
INPUT=/etc/input
OUTPUT=/etc/output

mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"
for file in "$INPUT"/* ; do
  gzip -c "$file" > "${OUTPUT}/${file}.gz"
done
```

Change `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` to match what you want.

Comment: For loop gets goobered up when idjits have spaces in their file names.