# how much multiprocess can speed up on compress task?

Tags: bash, multithreading, compression, xz

I have a large compress task (compress 10000 large file( > 10 G each))

I found `xz -z` or `gzip` are slow.

So, i want to use multiprocess to make the compress parallelized.

but i heard the high IO task's limit is on IO speed.

I am not so good in hardware design.

So, can multiprocess speed up compress?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166037/2836621

Comment: Hey to use `fxz` or `zpaq` both work with several threads. For compression or decompression.

Comment: If you're doing 100TB of disk reading, and several TB of writing, I hope your disk subsystems are well configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. Compression is usually compute bound, not I/O bound. You can use [pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz) to get close to a factor of *n* speedup for *n* cores.